# Changing color of a specific character in an item in CListCtrl in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl and I need to change the color of A SPECIFIC character/set of characters (which I choose by comparison) from the text of every cell in the list.

I know how to change the color of the entire text of the cell when I find the character/set of characters (by using 'strstr' command), but I can't find an example which shows how to change ONLY the character/set of characters.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    void Agenda::OnCustomdrawMyList( NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult )
    {
        NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = (NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*)pNMHDR;

        *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

        if (CDDS_PREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
        {
            *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            return;
        }else if (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
        {
            *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
            return;
        }else if ( (CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT) == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage )
        {

            // So right now I am in the stage where a SUBITEM is PREPAINTED

            int nItem = pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
            int nSubItem = pLVCD->iSubItem;

            char a[100];
            listControl.GetItemText(nItem,nSubItem,a,100);

            COLORREF textColorFound, textColorDefault;
            textColorDefault = RGB(0,0,0);
            pLVCD->clrText = textColorDefault;

            char* startingFrom;

            if( (startingFrom = strstr(a,filterText)) != NULL ) {
                    // Could I set a pointer here or something like that so
                    //   the coloring could start only from 'startingFrom'
                    //   and stop at 'strlen(filterText)' characters?

                textColorFound = RGB(205,92,92);
                pLVCD->clrText = textColorFound;
            }
            *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        }
    }
```

- listControl is the variable for my CListCtrl
- the other things are pretty self-explanatory

Comment: I would say you need to owner-draw the subitems. The custom draw solution you are using only lets you change the properties (text or background color, font...) of the whole subitem, and then the list draws it with those properties. One thing that comes to mind, that I haven't tried, is to override the drawing in the CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT phase. But that's pretty much owner-drawing it after it has been drawn. But you can select when you need to do it.

Comment: I though I could avoid using CustomDraw, but I'll start looking. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this. What you will have to do is custom-draw the text in question. This will be tricky because you will have to do it with two different calls, between which you will have to manually adjust the color and the drawing location to account for the intercharacter spacing etc. And you *better* hope that you don't need to do multi-line output.

Take a look at the article [Neat Stuff to Do in List Controls Using Custom Draw](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra) by Michael Dunn on CodeProject to get some ideas on how to proceed.

Alternatively, if you can use the [Toolkit Pro](http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/) toolkit from CodeJock you can leverage their "XAML" support (I use quotes because it's not *really* XAML, but their own implementation of a *subset* of XAML) and let them do all the hard work.

Comment: <blockquote> manually adjust the color and the drawing location </blockquote> So how can I do this? This is what I am looking for. I know that tutorial from codeproject. What I've done so far is from there.

Comment: You cannot do that on a per-character basis. You can do it for the *entire* string.

Answer (score 0):

Digging on the same issue; But I wouldn't go so far as modifying/adding to the default Windows behaviour for painting strings... apparently that would be the endpoint of having it owner-drawn.(aici am murit si eu :).